# Why does StorageManagement keep quitting whenever I want to look at storage?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, storage

So recently I have been noticing that I have lost about 12 GB of storage randomly. Of course, I loaded up Daisy Disk and try to find the issue (with no luck unfortunately), so I decided to see what I could do with the Apple Storage Managment features.

So I headed over to **Apple** -> **About This Mac** -> **Storage** to look at the summary. I see the following screen:

[image]

A few seconds later, this pops up:

[image]

The Storage panel keeps on "calculating", and I cannot use the default functions provided in Manage Storage. Does anyone know how to fix this? I am on a MacBook Pro Mid-2014 on macOS Sierra 10.12.5

Comment: You may need to rebuild the Spotlight index. [This page at Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT2017160) shows you how. It may take some time, depending on the number of files and directory complexity. Start it running in the evening before you sleep and it should be done in the morning.

Comment: @IconDaemon Let me try that out. I will post how it goes here.

Comment: @IconDaemon that did not seem to work unfortunately. I still have the issue.

Comment: I suggest you boot into the Restore partition (Command-R immediately when you press the power button at Start up or at a Restart) and run [Disk Utility](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH22243?locale=en_US) to check the disk for problems. Some errors you may be able to fix. Others may tell you to reinstall macOS. Report back your findings.

Comment: @IconDaemon I tried Reindexing Spotlight by using CleanMyMac3, and that seemed to fix my issue. Can you please post your solution in an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reindex the Spotlight Index by following these steps:

- Choose Apple menu () > System Preferences, then click Spotlight.
- Click the Privacy tab.
- Drag the folder or disk that you want to index
  again to the list of locations that Spotlight is prevented from
  searching. Or click the Add (+) button and select the folder or disk
  to add.

*To add an item to the Privacy tab, you must have ownership permissions for that item. To learn about permissions, choose Help from the Finder menu bar, then search for “permissions.”*

- From the same list of locations, select the folder or disk that you just
  added. Then click the Remove (–) button to remove it from the list.
- Quit System Preferences. Spotlight will reindex the contents of the
  folder or disk.

From: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201716